# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout + UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource: is there a way to change a decoration view depending on section data?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that uses `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and it works fine.

Cells are provided by a cellProvider defined in the initialiser of the datasource. The provider returns cells with indexPath specific data.

Supplementary views are provided by a `var supplementaryViewProvider: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SectionIdentifierType, ItemIdentifierType>.SupplementaryViewProvider`

Only problem: I did not find something like a `DecorationViewProvider`:

Following the WWDC 2019 example, I use

```
layout.register(SectionBackgroundDecorationView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: 
    MyCompositionalCollectionViewController.sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind)
```

and

```
        let sectionBackgroundDecoration = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(
            elementKind: MyCompositionalCollectionViewController.sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind)
        section.decorationItems = [sectionBackgroundDecoration]
```

to provide a background view for a section.

Problem:
Since I did not find a provider, the background decoration view is initialised automatically so I did not find a way to change it depending on section data.

For example I'd like to set a different color to the background decoration view depending on the section.

How do I let the background decoration view know which section it belongs to or how do I set properties depending on the section?

(Only dirty hack that comes to my mind: I could write 20 different classes `SectionBackgroundDecorationView1`, `SectionBackgroundDecorationView2`, use a different `forDecorationViewOfKind:` for each and each class has hard coded that it belongs to section 0, section 1 ... there has to be a better solution)

Comment: I believe the only way to specify decoration views for a section is via the `decorationItems` property. So, I don't think you can avoid having to register as many decoration views as you have different backgrounds (which I agree is not ideal). However, you can assign decoration views to the appropriate sections by initializing your layout via `init(sectionProvider:)`. Just infer the section identifier using the closure's section index and return each section configured with the appropriate decoration view. This may be more or less the solution you've already proposed though.

Comment: Yes, I'm already initializing my layout via `init(sectionProvider:)` . The problem is that the configuration dos not happen with a view but a `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem`. The only variable parameter here is `elementKind` which is my ugly trick.